# Ionic 2 - How do I implement versioning on a sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework

How do I go about implementing versioning for a sqlite database for an Ionic 2 application?

I am talking about when a new version of the app is installed and being able to tell which version of the database was there and what needs to be done to it for the current install.. i.e. alter statements, create new tables, etc. Android has the OpenHelper that has an onUpgrade method that you can override.

Comment: Please make a [mcve] with accompanying more information on what you want exactly.

Comment: In particular, what do you mean by versioning - I assume you're not just referring to keeping the data in a revision control system?

Comment: No, I am talking about when a new version of the app is installed and being able to tell which version of the database was there and what needs to be done to it for the current install..   i.e. alter statements, create new tables, etc.  Android has the OpenHelper that has an onUpgrade method that you can override.